# Is socket.io connection only triggered on page load?

Tags: socket.io-1.0

I have a node application and users need to login. We don't want to refresh the page after logging them in. The problem is we cannot add their sockets by their user id if not refreshed. I'm thinking if there are some alternatives for this, rather than refreshing the page.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that socket id is saved in cookies. I just get it from the cookies after login then saved it to usersSocketList. This solved my problem.